# Grails and Atmosphere: Rendering templates in a service using Atmosphere push

Tags: grails, push-notification, atmosphere

I'm using Atmosphere 1.0.12 to push data from a server to my clients in a Grails 2.2.1 application.

The application is an auction Web site, and I'm pushing updates such as prices, bidder information, and status messages. The goal is to change information dynamically on the page without requiring a page reload. Some of the information is very easy to update, such as a price change after a bid. But other things require some logic, such as telling a user they are the high bidder, or have been outbid.

Currently I've implemented an Atmosphere service (LotPushService) to push the information.

However, after these updates, certain information is missing, such as user information and locale, because this isn't sent along with the updates and isn't being handled by the service.

Is it possible to use the service to render page templates when it sends the push update, so that session and state information is preserved?

Are there any best practices for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the [BroadcasterCache?](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-BroadcasterCache) At least you should in order to not lose messages.